# Remove LoginActivity from Manifest - Facebook SDK for Android 3.0

Tags: android, facebook

I notice that Facebook SDK 3.0 has to have the LoginActivity declaration in Manifest file.

```
<activity android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"
          android:label="@string/app_name" />
<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/applicationId" />
```

If it's not there, the below exception is thrown.

```
com.facebook.FacebookException: Cannot use SessionLoginBehavior SSO_WITH_FALLBACK when com.facebook.LoginActivity is not declared as an activity in AndroidManifest.xml
```

It seems a bad practice when Facebook SDK has to depend on this declaration. I wonder if there is a way to remove it from Manifest file.

About the applicationId missing, I can pass it in code by modifying some functions, LoginButton constructor and Session constructor.

Comment: Is there any reason for you not to include it in the manifest?

Comment: Because the client project must declare it in Manifest. it's a dependency.

Comment: True, but you also need to declare internet permissions in the manifest (another dependency), and you need to add the SDK to the app in the first place. Are there any details that are preventing you from including another activity in the manifest?

Comment: but how to manage the launcher activity then?

Answer (score 6):

When using the official build stack, you need to reference every Activity (that needs to be started) in your manifest. This is indeed counter-intuitive, since one would expect such things to be inherited from included libraries.

A process known as "manifest merging" is right now possible with the [Maven](https://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/) build stack and with the [new build system](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system). Since the new build system is still work-in-progress, you just have to wait until it is being rolled out officially.

Comment: Manifest merging works in ADT/Eclipse too. You just need to add this line to the non-library project's `project.properties` file: `manifestmerger.enabled=true`

Answer (score 2):

As the error suggests put the declaration as follow in your manifest:

```
<activity android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"
          android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
          android:label="@string/app_name" />
```

Comment: Your answer has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: @AlvaroSantisteban why do u think so?